# What do comments with @param and @return mean in Google App Scripts?

Tags: google-apps-script, jsdoc

I keep seeing this kind of thing in the library I'm currently working with:

```
/**
 * Builds a pie chart from data in a specific column.
 *
 * @param  {Object[][]} data a JavaScript 2d array
 * @param  {int} columnIndex the index of the column from which the chart should be created
 * @param  {int} optfilter the index of the column used to add a filter to the chart
 * @return {ChartPanel} a panel containing chart & filter. 
 */
```

I saw something along the lines that it was helping with autocomplete in the code that the library is being used. What does it do and how does it work?

Comment: Looks like Doxygen comments: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doxygen

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are tools that can build documentation from comments if you follow a specified syntax.

@param begins a line that documents parameters to the function, @return documents the expected return value with type and description.

Answer (score 2):

You're right. These things are part of JavaDoc and provide documentation for functions (and properties and classes). Similar to Intellisense pop-up hints on .NET.

An example what this would look like in eclipse:

[image]

([Image Source](http://archive.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/drops/R-3.5-200906111540/eclipse-news-part2.html))

Answer (score 1):

They are part of automatic documentation system with which one could quickly fetch an information about function's parameters and return types.

Answer (score 1):

`@param` and `@return` are some of the few JSDoc tags supported by Google Apps Script.

Custom functions (user-defined functions for Google Sheets formulas), together with `@customfunction`, are used to specify formula help to show to the user in the Google Sheets user interface. See [Autocomplete](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions#autocomplete), a section from the Custom Functions article from the guide Extend Google Sheets with Google Apps Script.

JSDoc style documentation is also used by Google Apps Script libraries to instruct the autocomplete feature to be shown to the user. Ref. https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions#autocomplete

Resources

- https://jsdoc.app/